# Draw and fill a signal

Tags: c#, drawing

I would like to draw and then fill a signal using graphics.drawcurve and graphics.fillclosedcurve as following:

Graphics

```
gX = drawPanel.CreateGraphics();
Pen pen1 = new Pen(Color.Black); 
Brush be = new SolidBrush(Color.Gray);
gX.DrawCurve(pen1, pointArray1, 0.01F);
gX.FillClosedCurve(be, pointArray1);
```

Although there is no minus in the plotted data I got some filled curved at the minus side of the curve (due to interpolation?) as following:

[image: Filled signal]

How can I get rid of these artifacts?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what values you have in "pointArray1" ?

Comment: @H.Mahida It is a signal consists of 100 data points which all the minus values were zeroed. I am not sure if I put all the double values here

Comment: try with only few data which makes only two curve, and see what happens..!!

Comment: No success. It is something to do with the .drawcurve function. What else I can use?

Comment: Do not use curves! They tend to overdraw esp. when the direction changes quickly. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30791706/gdi-curve-overflowing/30793394#30793394)! Stick to DrawLines &  FillPolygon instead.

Comment: Thanks @TaW, I will try and see the results. I wonder if DrawLines can handle around 100M points

Comment: 100M? Really? On what size of bitmap would that be drawn??

Comment: @TaW, You are right, it works well (still not perfect) with DrawLines & FillPolygon. If you write your comment as an answer, I will accept it as correct. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `DrawCurves` to plot real data!

They look nice and are useful when creating a freehand plot of your mouse movements.

But when plotting data they are not so good as they tend to **overdraw** esp. when the direction changes quickly.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30791706/gdi-curve-overflowing/30793394#30793394) for an instructive example of overdrawing!  Setting a `Tension` is a way to limit the problem; but it will also limit the smoothness of the lines..

The solution there uses `Beziers`, but this not what you should do!

With the great number of dara points you seem to have I suggest you stick to `DrawLines` & `FillPolygon` instead; they still should look rather smooth..